# Passing a string with apostrophe to javascript function

Tags: javascript, escaping

I have a situation where I need to pass a string with an apostrophe in it to a javascript function.  This function then takes the string and uses it to find the element by id in the DOM.  As an example, I need to call:

```
showElement('what's')

function showElement(element_id){
     document.getElementById(element_id).style.display = "block";
}
```

I tried escaping the apostrophe like showElement('what\'s') but that did not seem to work.  Is this possible at all?

Comment: As a general rule, I would say stay away from using apostrophe's in your element IDs.

Comment: i believe using apostrophes for an element ID is invalid html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have entirely different problem here. `id` attribute can't have `'` symbols inside and you won't be able to search for such an id with `getElementById`. Escaping works though, just not in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [JavaScript Escape Characters](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/tutorial/javascript_escape_characters.cfm)

Try using a backslash \

Something like

```
showElement('what\'s') 

function showElement(element_id){ 
     document.getElementById(element_id).style.display = "block"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
showElement("what's")
```

Double quote around string with single quote inside.